Amazon S3 bucket requirements for create spot-datafeed-subscription
I want to create a spot-datafeed-subscription with the documentation on Track your Spot Instance costs by subscribing to a data feed - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud.
I am kind of lost in how I have to configure my s3 bucket in order to have the subscription work.
The suggestions from Trying to create AWS spot datafeed, getting error: InaccessibleStorageLocation - Stack Overflow
did not got me to my goal.
When I type in the command:
aws ec2 create-spot-datafeed-subscription --bucket my-bucket

I always get:

An error occurred (InaccessibleStorageLocation) when calling the CreateSpotDatafeedSubscription operation: The specified bucket does not exist or does not have enough permissions

However,
aws ec2 create-spot-datafeed-subscription --bucket my-bucket --dry-run

results in

An error occurred (DryRunOperation) when calling the CreateSpotDatafeedSubscription operation: Request would have succeeded, but DryRun flag is set.


The documentation seems to be saying that it will add the required permissions to the S3 bucket, but you will need to have FULL_CONTROL permission on the bucket. It's hard to see who has this permission, but if you look at the Permission tab of the bucket there is a Canonical ID for the Bucket Owner. If this is set to your Canonical ID, it should supposedly work fine. See also: Access control list (ACL) overview - Amazon Simple Storage Service

Thank you for your reply. Finally, it was actually a problem with the user I worked with and single sign on. I renewed my credential-file and now it works.

Great! Feel free to add your own Answer to help future readers!
